# Application of Discount Code results in crazy amounts, new discount codes do not work

Tags: civievent, cividiscount

I use CiviCRM for Joomla. After upgrading CiviCrm 4.7.27 to CiviCRM 4.7.29 following problems came up in module CiviEvent using CiviDiscount:

- a EUR discount results in crazy figures (e.g. a 100 EUR discount from 780 turns to be 779.999.999.900,00  instead of 680)
- new discount codes dont work at all

The database cividiscount_item shows correct values, also the new values are added there.
So problems seems to arise after hitting "APPLY" - Button with id and name "_qf_Register_reload" in the CiviEvent-form

It looks like being related to the decimal sign "." or ",", but till now I have no clue checkign the code in cividiscount.php around line 420

Everything worked fine before the upgrade of CiviCRM

Answer (score 3):

I found this issue as regression to CiviDiscount ext due to CRM-21562 changes. Submitted a PR https://github.com/dlobo/org.civicrm.module.cividiscount/pull/190 against CiviDiscount ext. Can you please test this patch and if possible provide your feedback in the PR itself, that will be helpful in getting it merged?

Thanks!

Comment: Added the 3 lines and it worked for me ! Thx.

Answer (score 0):

This was a recent issue with some recent CiviCRM release.

See [CRM-21562: Currencies (like Euro) with a comma for thousand separator are being seriously mishandled](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-21562) for the recent report and fix discussion. The discussion there suggests this issue is believed to be resolved in 4.7.29 - affected sites (like yours) will need to reach out ([JIRA](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-21562) or [~dev-financial in CiviCRM chat](https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/pl/z9ehyca5b7r78jjtr783wp6n7e)) to report their experience.

Comment: Other relevant tickets (mostly older): [CRM-21350: Dummy payment processor throws error with different decimal delimitor than "."](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-21350), [CRM-16034](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16034), [CRM-10974](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-10974), [CRM-15835](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-15835), [CRM-6391](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-6391)

Comment: Thx for the hint - it seems to be the cause. I also have the problem CRM-21350 on my site https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-21350